# Scaffold-DbContext does not work with SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core and .NET Core 2.1. I am trying to run the EF designer from the Package Manager Console on Windows, but I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: The string argument 'storeTypeName' cannot be empty.

This is the command which results in the error above:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Filename=switches.db" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Models
```

I have already tried using the full path to the `.db` file but I got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because one of your tables have a column with no defined type. It is fixed in the upcoming version 2.2 (currently available in preview on nuget) https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13531

Comment: Thanks! Moved to the preview versions of the EF libraries in the project and it generated the files.